# How to inject different dependencies for parent/child activities from multiple independent components using Dagger 2?

Tags: java, android, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I'm relatively new to Dagger 2, and I kept running into compiler error from Dagger 2 says missing `@Provide` or `@Produces`. What I'm trying to do is inject common components in base class, then child class also has its own component. I checked out several examples online and saw people using sub-component; but I still don't get why can we just have multiple independent components for each class? I don't see why my `ImageComponent` has to be sub-component of `ApiComponent`, it just doesn't make any sense. So I'm wondering what's the right approach regarding this issue, or is there any alternative approach that I'm not aware of? Thanks.

`Api Component`

```
public interface UserApi {

    int getUser();
}

public interface SearchApi {

    int search();
}

@Singleton
@Module
public class ApiModule {

    public ApiModule() {
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public SearchApi provideSearchApi() {
        return new SearchApi() {
            @Override
            public int search() {
                return 0;
            }
        };
    }

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    public UserApi provideUserApi() {
        return new UserApi() {
            @Override
            public int getUser() {
                return 0;
            }
        };
    }
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules = {
    ApiModule.class
})
public interface ApiComponent {

    void inject(BaseActivity activity);
}
```

`Image Component`

```
public interface ImageLoader {

    boolean load(String url);
}

@ActivityScope
@Module
public class ImageModule {

    @ActivityScope
    @Provides
    public ImageLoader provideImageResource() {
        return new ImageLoader() {
            @Override
            public boolean load(String url) {
                return false;
            }
        };
    }
}

@ActivityScope
@Component(
    modules = {
        ImageModule.class
    }
)
public interface ImageComponent {
    // Dagger doesn't allow this? Not sure why?
    void inject(MainActivity activity);
}
```

`Activity and Components Singleton`

```
public class Components {

    private ApiComponent apiComponent;

    private ImageComponent imageComponent;

    private static Components singleton;

    public static void initialize(Context context) {
        if (singleton != null) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Attempted to initialize components twice");
        }
        singleton = new Components(context);
    }

    public static Components get() {
        return singleton;
    }

    private Components(Context context) {
        apiComponent = ApiComponent
            .builder()
            .dataModule(new ApiModule())
            .build();

        // Can't generate image component yet
    }

    public ApiComponent api() {
        return apiComponent;
    }

    public ImageComponent image() {
        return imageComponent;
    }
}
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Inject
    protected UserApi userApi;

    @Inject
    protected SearchApi searchApi;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Components.get().data().inject(this);
    }
}

public class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {

    @Inject
    protected ImageLoader imageLoader;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

`stacktrace`

```
Error:(15, 10) error: android.com.dagger.data.UserApi cannot be provided without an @Provides- or @Produces-annotated method.
android.com.dagger.BaseActivity.userApi
[injected field of type: android.com.dagger.data.UserApi userApi]
```

Comment: try annotating the function in ImageModule with @Provides

Comment: @Bhargav: Yeah, I did that. It was a typo in the post, let me fixed that. Thanks.

Comment: Post the stack trace of error if possible

Comment: @Bhargav: added. Thanks.

Comment: So `UserApi` is an interface? and in the provides method you are actually just returning an anonymous class yes? Instead try creating a class that implements these interfaces and returning a new instance of that class instead of returning anonymous classes

Comment: Also this method should return BaseActivity `void inject(BaseActivity activity);` not void

Comment: Also why is the UserApi in this namespace `android.com.dagger.data.UserApi` doesn't make sense `android.com` ? why would you use a namespace like that

Comment: @Bhargav: Just for demo purposes, I wouldn't for real app :)

Comment: anyway trying using concrete implementation classes instead of anonymous classes and tell me what happens

Comment: base classes are not sufficient as injection targets. Dagger 2 relies on strongly typed classes, so you must specify explicitly which ones should be defined

Comment: You can;t do this `Components.get().data().inject(this);` this (i.e BaseActivity is abstract)

Answer (score 4):

base classes are not sufficient as injection targets. Dagger 2 relies on strongly typed classes, so you must specify explicitly which ones should be defined

You can't do this `Components.get().data().inject(this);`  `this` (i.e `BaseActivity` is abstract)